How to answer questions from apt install without getting prompted?
I'm trying to install a package without getting prompted. The answer I found online was to use this which is working perfectly fine for the package that I'm installing;
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install myPackage -y

However, recently I switched to another Cloud provider and running the same command on the same Ubuntu 20.04 server doesn't yield the same result. This time it fails. I believe they're using different Ubuntu 20.04 versions (most likely regular vs minimal). By "fails" I mean it still prompts me, even when run from a bash script.
I tried different methods such as the following but nothing answers the last question that the package is asking which is simply a yes/no question and even in the interactive GUI I can't just press enter to answer yes. It forces me to type yes.
Also the above command still prompts me with the black and white text GUI even though I have noninteractive set.
Methods I tried that didn't work;
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical
sudo apt-get install -y myPackage

yes yes | sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y myPackage

DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive /usr/bin/apt-get --option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold --option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io --assume-yes --quiet install myPackage

How can I get this to work so I can answer the questions with just default answers without getting prompted? It was working fine on one Ubuntu 20.04 server but it's not working on another from a different provider.

Could you run env -i bash and then run one of these commands again? Maybe something else is set in the environment that forces apt-get to ask a question.

Also, can you show the full command with the name of the specific package you're trying to install?

sudo doesn't inherit your environment except some very specific bits for security reasons. Please consult the sudo manpage to get what you want.

Installing apt-utils solved the issue. Now noninteractive works as intended.
apt install apt-utils


I think you should be able to do just:
sudo apt install -y myPackage

I think any of the 'export'd env variables will be dropped as soon as you enter 'sudo' land because its a different user space.
Seems similar to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236670/debian-frontend-noninteractive-not-working-inside-shell-script-with-apt-get

This is still prompting me with a black and white text-based GUI. I'm running as root btw.

@MarryJane: if you are running as root, why do you use sudo?

apt and its derivatives (apt-get, apt-cache, ...) are just frontends to the Debian package manager, which is dpkg. You could use
dpkg -i [pkg-file]

to install a package file you have downloaded from the repository server.
See man dpkg for more information on this.

You're doing everything right with DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y! Any correct .deb package would use apt-get's facilities to talk to you (the user), and when you tell apt-get (or apt) (or rather the underlying dpkg command, not that that matters here) that you don't want to be asked, that would settle that. Problem solved!
However, as demonstrated, there's software vendors that just build broken packages. If this is a package from Ubuntu's software repos, then that would warrant a bug report, and the package should be fixed pretty quickly.
The stupid "type yes" approach leads me to believe that this is some third-party package with some license bull… questionable EULA wrapper.
What happens here is this: a package is just an archive file, with

the files that should be installed
a directory containing

Package metadata (what is in here? what does it depend on?)
(optionally) Scripts that need to be executed before and/or after putting the files where they should go, and/or after and/or before uninstalling the package.



And in your case, there's a package that's got a script, either post- or pre-installation that asks you nastily.
So, our mission is to modify the package!
TO BE CONTINUED; I HAVE TO LEAVE NOW

I fixed it by installing apt-utils. Now it works just fine!

@Marcus apt-get doesn’t provide facilities to query the user. Packages are supposed to use debconf for that but there isn’t a strict obligation. Even with debconf there are a variety of circumstances that can cause unwanted prompting. (The solution here doesn’t explain much — apt-utils changes the order of events, it shouldn’t hide questions.)
